# MVC Helper TextArea - Placeholder not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have the following code in my .cshtml:

```
 @Html.TextArea("txtComments", new { style = "width: 450px;", placeholder = "Enter Comments here" })
```

But the placeholder is not displaying at all. Am I missing something?

Source:

```
<textarea cols="20" id="txtComments" name="txtComments" placeholder="Enter Comments here" rows="2" style="width: 450px;">
</textarea>
```

Comment: As I said, the code is working, it's displaying your placeholder. Are you sure it's not a problem with your `CSS`?

Comment: Dono whatz causing. Am trying in an empty page without Css also but still not coming up..Weird

Comment: What browser are you currently using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put an @ before the style and placerholder, like so, maybe even put `htmlAttributes:` before it.

```
@Html.TextArea("txtComments", htmlAttributes: new { @style = "width: 450px;", @placeholder = "Enter Comments here" })
```

And this is the *exact* output I get:

```
<textarea cols="20" id="txtComments" name="txtComments" placeholder="Enter Comments here" rows="2" style="width: 450px;"></textarea>
```

If this shows a placeholder but it still isn't showing, make sure you're using an up-to-date web browser, you can find a list of the supported browsers here: http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

```
< IE10 does not support it.
```

If you do need support in those browsers, maybe this solution will help you: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text

Comment: Then something else is the problem as that code works for me. Can you post the `html` that is generated by your `@Html.TextArea` line? Check that the placeholder isn't there but your css has stopped it dispalying.

Comment: should be a bowser thing. am using IE8. Thanks

Comment: Consider upgrading to browser which supports modern `internet`s, such as [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) or [Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/). This will fix your issues but remember, anyone using your apps who uses old browsers will not be able to see placeholders. Bear this in mind.

Comment: yes i have chrome. But my client uses IE. so i use for DEV :)  Thanks

Comment: i cant Vote up . i need 15 :D

Comment: No problem, there are fixes for IE I'm sure. Deploy the Google fu!

Comment: Interesting, this works: `new { @placeholder = "Into / Teaser Text" } )` but this does not:  `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Friendly Url" } }` nor does it work with `@placeholder`

Comment: Dan Beauliei: This was my issue! Thanks. Your comment fixed mine. I removed the "htmlAttributes" but and just started with new { and now it works! Winner, thanks mate.

Comment: Me too! I moved it forward into the first new and it works for TextAreaFor.:     Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OtherComments, new { placeholder = "Optional", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows = "4", cols = "50"} })
EditorFor it goes in htmlAttributes area. I used "@" for both.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me (asp.net v4.6.2 mvc5) :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MyMessageForm.MessageText, new { placeholder = "Your msg here...", @class = "form-control" } )
```